# NSString with length

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have this below string:

```
 `NSString *myStr = @"APPLE";`
```

Now I use this code to show first letter:

```
  NSLog(@"%@", [myStr substringToIndex:1];
```

Tell me please, how can I show my string like that:

A _ _ _ _

Comment: I know it became unpopular to ask this, but [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: NSString *finalText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[myStr substringToIndex:1], [myStr substringToIndex:NSMakeRange(2, [myStr length]-2)]];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but I think you want this:

```
NSString *myStr = @"APPLE";
NSString *finalText = [[myStr substringToIndex:1] stringByPaddingToLength:myStr.length withString: @"_" startingAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", finalText);
```